# Optimizing QgsFeatureRequest with filter expression

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, expression, optimization

I have a point PostGIS layer (my_layer) which has more than 66000 features. I am getting the features I want but it takes too long. My code is:

```
    resultList = []
    req = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(' "some_field_name" = \'some_value\' ')
    for feat in my_layer.getFeatures(req):
        name = feat.attribute("some_other_field")
        resultList.append(name)
```

How can I optimize it so that I can get the results quicker?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

QGIS API provides you with a couple of ways for optimizing features requests.

In your case, if you don't need geometry and the rest of attributes in the result, you can:

- Use flag `NoGeometry` (see [docs](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html#aab0dc2dca2b882316c3bb3668dbf4667)).
- Set subset of attributes you really need using `setSubsetOfAttributes()` (see [docs](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html#a85f831f339a9882822d5d5cf19b29fdf)).

That should speed your request up.

Answer (score 6):

Another suggestion which may also help - make sure you have a suitable index created on your field on the Postgres database, and then switch on the option under Settings -> Data Sources -> "Execute expressions on server-side if possible". That should make a huge difference, as all the filtering will be done on the server rather then sending ALL the features in the layer to QGIS to filter.