# createFieldEqualityExpression usage

Tags: pyqgis, performance

I'm looking for an efficient way to filter my 700.000 features by attribute in PyQGIS. As suggested in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245909/selecting-features-by-attribute-in-qgsvectorlayer-faster)  It looks like using `QgsExpression` for such a job is a fastest way? Or is there a faster approach? I'm filtering using integers in indexed columns on my database.

Now when it comes to API I've noticed there is a :

```
for feature in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression.createFieldEqualityExpression('field_name', value))):
```

do something with feature

Any speed up suggestions?  Is using list comprehension with filtering faster way to go about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`createFieldEqualityExpression` return a string so I was able to use it as such:

```
features = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(QgsExpression.createFieldEqualityExpression(field_name, value)))
for feat in features:
    #code using the features
    pass
```