# Selecting features in multiple columns by attribute using ArcMap without Python code

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select-by-attribute

I am using ArcMap.

I have a shapefile with multiple features and multiple fields. Some of the field values are repetitive and I would like to apply a filter to select according to them. E.g. By searching for 'value_1' in the entire attribute table I would like to select all the geometries that contain this value.

There are methods to select by attribute with code (e.g. [Selecting features by attribute in QgsVectorLayer faster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245909) which uses PyQGIS) but I am searching for an ArcMap method without code.

Using the Select By Attribute tool is not an option because there are more than 100 columns.

Comment: Because this field query is used by a client who prefers having a non-python solution.

Comment: Use Modelbuilder, copy paste and modify the query 100 times

Comment: Use Find - binocular button.