# Optimizing intersections and rubber band representations with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, intersection, optimization, qgsrubberband

I made a tool which runs a [QgsMapToolEmitPoint](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapToolEmitPoint.html) object. Also set its [canvasMoveEvent](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapToolEmitPoint.html#a343d77c3b89e585a9d1f30ab5dcbc5a0) to create a polygon rubberband that takes a geometry from a feature that intersected with current tool's cursor position.

I.e., I move a pointer and each movement loops the whole layer until intersecting polygon is found. Then a rubberband with this polygon appears.

Here how it looks like:

[image]

But still I'm not satisfied with a speed of rubberband appearing. There is a small delay between pointer stop and polygon selection. A layer has about 160 features but to my opinion there should be a way to speed up getting an intersecting polygon.

I did a simple loop like this

```
for f in self.in_layer.getFeatures():
    if f.geometry().intersects(start_geom_point):
        f_selected = f 
        f_geometry = f.geometry()
        break
```

Also tried a `processing.run("qgis:selectbylocation")` but result was also not too good.
As far as I see it is something about basic methods of selecting features from multiple layers with a geometry relations. Is there any way to increase the speed of finding a single intersecting feature here?

Comment: Have you looked at spatial index? https://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsSpatialIndex.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nice question!

You can apply several optimizations, like these 5:

**1. Remove any `print()` statement.**

Print statements are nice for debugging (although there are better options, [see this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/216444/4972)). However, in production you shouldn't have any print statements because they could degrade performance when placed inside certain methods or loops.

**2. Optimize `getFeatures()` call.**

Since you are not interested in attributes, you should discard them. That is, use a request like this when getting all features from your layer (more details [in this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/195448/4972)):

```
   layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setNoAttributes())
```

**3. Cache the `getFeatures()` response.**

Chances are you don't need to call `getFeatures()` more than once in your code. Therefore, just call it once and traverse a member list of features or a member `dict` of (id, geometry) pairs against which you can perform the intersects analysis. For example:

```
def __init__(self):
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setNoAttributes()
    self.polygons = list(layer.getFeatures(request))

def canvasMoveEvent(self):
    for polygon in self.polygons:
        # Now test intersections
```

**4. Use a Spatial Index.**

Testing intersections against polygons with a large number of vertices could be improved by first testing against their bounding boxes, which will help you discard a lot polygons that are simply too far away.

What is left is a set of "candidate" polygons (or ids), against which you can now test real intersections, that is, intersections against the real (possibly complex) geometries.

For that you need to:

**a)** Build the spatial index for your polygon layer.

**b)** Build a `dict` of (id, geometry) pairs.

**c)** Get your cursor position in map coordinates.

**d)** Use the bounding box of c) to perform a quick check against the spatial index and get candidate ids.

**e)** Iterate candidate ids to test intersections (this time, real polygon geometry from b) against c)). Stop when you get your first positive result.

**f)** Pass the resulting geometry from e) to your rubber band.

Like this:

```
def __init__(self, e):
    # ...
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setNoAttributes()
    self._feature_map = {f.id():f.geometry() for f in self.layer.getFeatures(request)}
    self._index = QgsSpatialIndex(self.layer)
    # ...

def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
    # ...
    pos = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
    point = QgsGeometry(QgsPoint(pos.x(), pos.y()))
    pointbb = point.boundingBox()
    candidates = self._index.intersects(pointbb)
    for candidate in candidates:
        if self._feature_map[candidate].intersects(point):
            self._rb.reset()
            self._rb.addGeometry(self._feature_map[candidate], self.layer)
    # ...
```

**5. Avoid unnecessary updates to the rubber band's geometry.**

When you're moving the mouse, chances are you're resetting the rubber band's geometry to the same polygon a large number of times. You can easily avoid it by caching the latest id set and comparing to it just before setting a new geometry to the rubber band. Like this:

```
def __init__(self, iface):
    # ...
    self._current_id = None

def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
    # ...
    for candidate in candidates:
        if self._feature_map[candidate].intersects(point):
            if candidate != self._current_id:
                self._current_id = candidate
                self._rb.reset()
                self._rb.addGeometry(self._feature_map[candidate], self.layer)
            return
    self._rb.reset()
    self._current_id = None
```

Applying all these recommendations, this is what you'll get using the World map (240 polygons):

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's the most impressive answer I ever got. Many thanks, I'll definitely test all thing you recommended! Especially for spatial index, just heard about them but didn't know how and where to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed and very informative answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I enjoy writing these kinds of posts.

Comment: @Germán excellent explanation!! I follow carefully your publications,
I would only like to complement the use of GEOS with:
engine = QgsGeometry.createGeometryEngine(i.geometry().constGet())
engine.prepareGeometry() after filtering with the spatial index the geometries that meet the condition are then evaluated with engine.contains(c.geometry().constGet())

Comment: @LuisPerez if you write a separate answer with a use of geometry engine, that would be very helpful and we make a final tip to make spatial selection as fast as possible :)

Comment: We could simply add it to the existing answer ;).

Comment: BTW @PavelPereverzev, if the answer I posted worked for you, don't forget to mark it as accepted and vote for it. That'll let other users know that it solved your question.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo sorry, forgot about that. Marked just now